# Get time range from a string

Tags: python, for-loop, get, python-datetime

I have a csv file which contains two columns, Hotel name(xxx)  and a string indicating the time it is open e.g.: `Mon-Thu, Sun 11:30 am - 10 pm  / Fri-Sat 11:30 am - 10:30 pm` . I want to get the list of hotels that are open at a specific time.
This is what I've tried:

```py
import csv
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1],'rt')
final = []
try:
  reader=csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
   print row
   final.append(row[0])
  print final
finally:
 f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

## read the data file

```
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_csv("os.path.join("C:\Users\me\Desktop","myCSVfile.csv"))
```

## finding trump tower in your dataframe

```
filter = data["Hotelname"]=="Trump tower"

dataiwannause=data.where(filter, inplace = True)
```

Alternative try:

```
dataiwannause=data[data.Hotelname=="Trump tower"]
dataiwannause=data[data[Hotelname]=="Trump tower"]
```

if you work with CSV files or XLSX files please get pandas... its really worth it
I didnt doublecheck the code, but its something like that you need i think.
I tried to work with csv reader, when i was new and it really sux compared to pandas.

Read the "10 minutes to pandas tutorial". It will save you so much time in the long run
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't read your csv with pandas and use '[loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)'?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file_path")
df = df.set_index("timestamp colum name")

time = input("timestamp")
print(df.loc[time,'hotel column name'])
```

Comment: can you please help me pseudo code ..how to get the list of hotel , if i put 12:30 pm ...